# Using different accounts on Remix JS VM mode

Tags: remix

Remix's Javascript VM-mode is great because of its convenience and speed, but there doesn't seem to be a way to interact with your contract using different test accounts. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in Remix there's an "Account" dropdown right beneath "Environment" (where you select Javascript VM). It provides five test accounts for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create locally a blockchain with 10 test accounts using "[testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc)", a fast Ethereum RPC client for testing and development.

1. Download and install testrpc and then run on terminal "test-rpc". You will then have the 10 accounts and their private keys.
2. In Remix choose Web3-provider and connect to localhost:8545, where your test-rpc runs.

Comment: That's a good workaround, thank you. I was hoping it would be possible to do with the VM alone (seems like switching account functionality would be pretty doable).

Comment: Turns out it is possible. Just provided the answer.